# Pass a variable to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a variable (ID) that I must pass to an NSMutableArray (`productRes`).
But it doesn't work:`productRes` remains empty. 
Do have an idea?

Here is productRes:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *productRes;
@synthesize productRes;
```

The code related to the ID:

```
if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_500_BYTES_PACK]){
        ID = 4;
}
else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_1000_BYTES_PACK])
{
        ID = 0;
}
else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_3000_BYTES_PACK]){
        ID = 2;
}
else if ([purchase_id isEqual: IAP_7500_BYTES_PACK]){
        ID = 5;
}

else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_20000_BYTES_PACK]){
        ID = 1;
}

else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_50000_BYTES_PACK]){
        ID = 3;
}
else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_ADD_BACKGROUNDS]){
    ID = 6;
}
else if ([purchase_id isEqual:  IAP_FULL_VERSION]){
        ID = 7;
    }

SKProduct *productSK = [self.productRes objectAtIndex:ID];
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: did you alloc/init the array?

Comment: You never created the array.

Comment: BTW, the way you set ID is not particularly good.  You should create an NSDictionary with your purchase_id as the key and the ID (encoded as an NSNumber) as the value.  This is much more easily maintained.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.productRes objectAtIndex:ID];`

Method `objectAtIndex` asks the array to return value at the given index. If the array is empty, logically, the method won't return anything.

It should actually crash if the array is empty so my guess is that the array is `nil`.

Adding an object to array is done by `addObject:` method, for example:

```
[self.productRes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ID]];
```

Comment: Of course, addObject will silently fail if productRes is nil.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work completely. Now productRes takes the ID, but productSK is empty.
Now my code is:
`[self.productRes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ID]];
SKProduct *productSK = [self.productRes objectAtIndex:ID];`

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, I am quite a noob ;)
Thanks for your help anyway!